# What's the difference between an Anchor and a Pose in arcore?

Tags: android, arcore

I'm reading about the arcore elements but I don't understand the real difference between an Anchor and a Pose. In the API an anchor is described as:

> Describes a fixed location and orientation in the real world. To stay at a fixed location in physical space, the numerical description of this position will update as ARCore's understanding of the space improves.

But I don't understand how the anchor stays "fixed" if it's being updated as the Arcore explores the 3D world, and how this differs from a Pose.

Comment: Yep, it's. I'll mark it as duplicate.

Comment: You're Welcome!